# Issue validating App using Sphero SDK in Xcode 7.1 beta (7B75)

Tags: validation, ios9, sphero-api, sphero, xcode7.1beta

I'm having an issue validating an iOS 9 app (via the Organizer window) in Xcode 7.1 beta (7B75) that links to the latest RobotKit and RobotUIKit frameworks available from the Sphero Developer site.

The validation fails with a message, and here's contents of the IDEDistribution.critical.log:

2015-10-06 21:55:03 +0000 [MT] Failed to generate distribution items with error: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo=0x7fb9a236fb40 {NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
2015-10-06 21:55:03 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo=0x7fb9a236fb40 {NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}

As a test, I deleted both Sphero embedded frameworks from the .xcarchive file that is being validated, so the issue points to something in those underlying frameworks. Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

I have an update. The issue turned out to be simple in hindsight. I added both the RobotUIKit and RobotKit frameworks to the "Embedded Binaries" section of the General tab for my target app in Xcode. They should ONLY be added to the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section. The Sphero framework is a pre-iOS 8 framework and thus appears to be statically linked.